# What are the valid Terraform Application Insights Web Test Government Geo-Locations?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, terraform-provider-azure

I’m using the `azurerm_application_insights_web_test` to create availability web tests in the Azure Government cloud, but am unable to find the correct values to use for the `geo_locations` attribute. My current use of `USGov Virginia` results in an error of ‘USGov Virginia’ is not a supported location.

I’m trying to find the valid values for the Azure Government Virginia, Texas, and Arizona geo locations.

The [Terraform example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_insights_web_test.html) lists the locations in a form like `us-tx-sn1-azr`, I'm just having a hard time finding any documentation for the Azure Government locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: documentation has been updated and now includes tags for both Public and Gov clouds (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#location-population-tags)

We're working on adding proper support of creating availability tests to all CLIs (which will not rely on Configuration field but instead will have native fields to express a web test). As a part of this work we will list available geo location attributes.

Meanwhile, please use this table for Azure Government:

```
"USGov Virginia" = "usgov-va-azr"
"USGov Arizona" = "usgov-phx-azr"
"USGov Texas" = "usgov-tx-azr"
"USDoD East" = "usgov-ddeast-azr"
"USDoD Central" = "usgov-ddcentral-azr"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you much.

Comment: perfect answer to the question asked, however, is it possible to get the complete list of values? I'm not running in a government cloud so need to know the valid values for vanilla azure.

Comment: Yes, documentation has tags for both clouds.